# Why does the BeautifulSoup select() method return empty list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

questions = soup.select('.question-summary')
print(questions)
```

This returns:

```
[]
```

From the information in the https://codewithmosh.com/courses/ python course I payed for, this should not had happened.

Why does this code return [`[]`]?

Comment: You entered a selector for the `class=` attribute, but the only thing with the value you are searching for is an `id="question-summary-73998958"`. My guess is that you want to select `"div[id="question-summary-73998958"]" if you want exactly one of these that you already know about, or `'.s-post-summary'` if you want all divs of the class - and I think they'll all have an `id` with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code returns `[]` because there is no element with the class `.question-summary`

You should always inspect the website first. As FLAK-ZOSO said, I also couldn't find any `question-summary` class in the HTML.

You can get the question titles using

```
question_titles = soup.select('.s-post-summary--content-title')
```

and question summaries by

```
question_summaries = soup.select('.s-post-summary--content-excerpt')
```

Example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


response = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

question_summaries = soup.select('.s-post-summary--content-excerpt')
print(question_summaries[0].text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

I inspected the source code of https://stackoverflow.com/questions, and noticed there's no class `question-summary` used.

But there's a `s-post-summary` and a `s-post-summary--stats-item` class, have you tried them?